# multiple install of python, package install by pip are in wrong directory windows

Tags: python-2.7, pip, anaconda

I know this similar question has been answered before but I made the mistake of installing python 2.7 after a Anaconda installation. Now when I use the pip function in cmd, it install the package in the python 2.7 folder and not the Anaconda folder. using python -m pip function in cmd I get:

```
c:/python27/python .exe -m pip
```

I just want to use the Anaconda directory instead of this.. any easy way to specify it?

thank you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change your PATH environment variable so that the Python 2.7 directories are removed. The easiest way is to uninstall this extra Python version. If you would like to edit the PATH directly, see here: https://superuser.com/a/284351/229278

To quote the answer for Windows:

> ## Windows
>
> ### GUI
>
> 1. Open `Control Panel » System » Advanced » Environment Variables`.
> 2. Type `control sysdm.cpl,,3` in the Run dialog (<kbd>[image: Win]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) and click `Environment Variables`.
>      For editing user variables you can also type
>
>    ```
>    %windir%\System32\rundll32.exe sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables
>    ```
>
>    in the Run dialog.
> 3. Right-click (My) Computer and click on Properties, or simply press <kbd>[image: Win]</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd>.
>
>    - In XP click on `Advanced » Environment Variables`.
>    - In Vista+ click on `Advanced system settings » Environment Variables`.
> 4. There are many other ways of reaching the same place, such as by typing "environment variables" in the Start Menu/Screen search box and so on.
>
> Environment variables in Windows are separated into user and machine/system specific values. You can view and edit their values there. Their current values upon launch are made available to all programs.
>
> There is also [Rapid Environment Editor](http://www.rapidee.com/en/about), which helps setting and changing environment variables in Windows without the need to go deep into the system settings. Another open source program for Windows with which the path environment can be edited very conveniently is [Path Editor](http://www.redfernplace.com/software-projects/patheditor/).